# Place or add character(s) on preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got f.e. a string

```
foo-bar/baz 123
```

and a pattern

```
#foo-(bar/baz)#
```

This pattern would give me the captured `bar/baz`,

But i would like to replace (sanitize) the `/` with a `-` to receive `bar-baz`.

Reason: i got a method that gets a string as parameter, and the regex pattern via config.
The tool around this is dynamically and will look up the returned match as an id.
But the target|entity to find is using `-` instead of `/´ in the id.

So i now *could* hard code some exception like *~"if is this adapter then replace this and that"* -

but i wonder if i could do that we regex.

Test code:

```
// Somewhere in a loop ...
$string = "foo-bar/baz 123"; // Would get dynamically as parameter.
$pattern = "#foo-(bar/baz)#"; // Would get dynamically from config.
// ...
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches) === 1) {
    // return $matches[1]; Would return captured id.
    echo var_export($matches, true) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Returns

```
array (
    0 => 'foo-bar/baz',
    1 => 'bar/baz',
)
```

Expected|Need

```
array (
    0 => 'foo-bar/baz',
    1 => 'bar-baz', // <-- "-" instead of "/"
)
```

So im searching a way to "match-replace".

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` to replace what is matched with something else.

Comment: `preg_match()` just returns what was matched. If you want to change it to something else, do that after you get the match.

Comment: So there is no way? I would have to add in the config then something like : `search_pattern` and `replace_pattern` :/

Comment: Or just hard-code it. `$match[1] = str_replace($match[1], '/', '-');`